# MQTT messaging over websockets and Mqtt protocol

Tags: node.js, mqtt

I have created my own mqtt broker/server using mosca in `node js`, this is running on `mqtt` and `http` protocols

```
var mosca = require('mosca');

var settings = {
    interfaces: [
        { type: "mqtt", port: 1883 },
        { type: "http", port: 1884, bundle: true, static: './' },
    ],
};

var server = new mosca.Server(settings);
server.on('ready', function () {
    console.log("ready");
});
```

I have made a client using [this](http://hivemq.com/demos/websocket-client/), I have code snippet which continuously publishes the message on a topic using defauly `mqtt://` protocol

```
var mqtt = require('mqtt');
var client = mqtt.connect('mqtt://localhost');
client.on('connect', function () {
    setInterval(function () {
        client.publish('testtopic/1', 'test payload');
    }, 1000);
});
```

in my html I am using a client as earlier mentioned in the link, I am unable to connect through `mqtt: protocol port number 1883`, however I am able to connected through `http port 1884` but still unable to receive subscribe topics which is published by my code snippet, However if I publish any topic from client this successfully show the the message.

what should I need to change in my code snippet above to receive topic subscription in my client.

**NOTE:** Client is exactly copy of [this](http://hivemq.com/demos/websocket-client/)

**UPDATE:**  client code on git hub [mqtt_client](https://github.com/Q930844N/mqtt_client)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

On the browser, the client only supports the MQTT over WebSockets protocol.

Edit Client:

```js
var mqtt = require('mqtt');

// Remove
// var client = mqtt.connect('mqtt://localhost');
var client = mqtt.connect('ws://localhost:1884/mqtt');

// Use ws not mqtt, and define use the port in http option


client.on('connect', function () {
    setInterval(function () {
        client.publish('testtopic/1', 'test payload');
    }, 1000);
});
```

Like `ws://broker.emqx.io:8083/mqtt` or `ws://broker.mqttdashboard.com:8000/mqtt`

Comment: So what I have to do for this ?

Comment: what changes required in my broker or client to communicate properly

Comment: so no need to change in the broker,